# Stop Visual Studio 2019 CTRL + mouse wheel changing the font size

Tags: visual-studio

I'm continually having to reset the font size in Visual Studio Pro 2019 (not VS Code). I would really love to disable that feature.

Any idea how?

Comment: Why? Are you constantly holding down the control key for no reason?

Comment: I type 10 hours a day, and I use every keyboard shortcut they have. I often have my finger on the CTRL key. It makes me a pretty fast coder... but this thing vexes. me. Have anything ... constructive ... to add?

Comment: Some constructive criticism: By applying proper keyboarding techniques taught in school, you should only ever have your finger on (or over) a required modifier key as needed for a keyboard shortcut (or mouse wheel combination in case of zoom) and then back to home row; it should never be hovering over a modifier key for longer than required. This will eliminate your problem of accidentally zooming when you mean to scroll.

Answer (score 0):

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=mouse%20wheel%20zoom&target=VS&category=Tools&vsVersion=&subCategory=All&sortBy=Relevance

From another post I got the idea to search the VS Marketplace for 'mouse wheel zoom', and I found several products. One did not install on VS 2019, but the second one did. Solved!!!